# Jenkins git-plugin auto-install and configure git on Windows slaves

Tags: git, build, jenkins, hudson-plugins, configuration-management

I have production Jenkins installed on RedHat server, with many Linux Slaves.
Git plugin works flawlessly on Linux slaves but I didn't find any way to make it autoinstall git on Windows slaves (like it does in Java,Maven and Ant).
[image]

If I can only make the Run Command work on Windows - this could be great... but it seems to run as sh - which is no good for Windows.

This makes me install git manually whenever I want to add Windows slave, which is no fun at all (don't ask why, I just can't create Windows image with git built-in).

Do you know of any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either move to Jenkins core [higher then 1.549](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21202) or use [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extra+Tool+Installers+Plugin).